# SUPEE 9767 V2 fail on Magento 1.8.1.0 CE

Tags: magento-1.8, patches, security, supee-9767

I am getting this error while patching :

```
can't find file to patch at input line 433
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 7f7b9d0..8618bca 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
```

File `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` is not there.
I also checked the original 1.8.1.0 and `Image.php` is also not in the zip.

What should I do?

Comment: is solved your issue?

Comment: not solved. i don't know which patch adds Image.php

Comment: Please let us know how to download patch 9767v2 for magento1810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because you are missing the `SUPEE-7405` patch. This patch adds the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` file.

I strongly suggest you run your website against magereport.com to check which patch you're missing and install the missing patches before this one.

Comment: I read this somewhere on this forum, i have run magereport and it says Security patch 7405 installed. It's already patched in the past. and I didn't see any Image.php on the patch 7405 file. Are you sure it's SUPEE-7405 ?

Comment: ok i found it on 7405 v1 instead of v1.1. I'll be back.

Comment: ok i patched 7405 v1, then v1.1 then 9767 works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Receiving the below error while installing V2 SUPEE 9767 patch

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
can't find file to patch at input line 433
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 7f7b9d0..8618bca 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.2.1.1-1.6.0.2.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 340.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 607.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 502.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/head-simple.phtml
```